# Provisioning in sailpoint iiq

Tags: java, sailpoint

This is the error I am facing when I am Performing user Provisioning for Active Directory. I have passed in Account Dn, password, First name, and last name. I access Request for an entitlement which belongs ad and the Task results show and throw this exception
An exception occurred while executing the RPCRequest: Errors returned from
IQService. "Attribute DistinguishedNamedoes does not contain the expected
character.

I tried returning all values throw a variable. Created a different OU for the same as well and tested for different Identities (Users).